# Show blanks for repeating row values in result

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the query below, I want to set the Charges, Payments, Adjustments, and Balance values as blank if the PB HAR ID and Provider ID columns have duplicate values, I want to do the same for HB HAR ID and Provider ID. The purpose of this is to not have these rows add up to an inflated total, because there are multiple rows for the same PB HAR ID and HB HAR ID; I still need to see the Provider ID though.

[image: SampleOutput]

Code:

```
WITH prov1 as
(
SELECT p.hsp_account_id
, p.other_prov_id  
, p.OTH_PRV_ROLE_C 
, zcp.NAME 

from dbo.HSP_ACCT_OTHR_PROV p

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ZC_OTH_PRV_ROLE_HA zcp
ON p.oth_prv_role_c = zcp.oth_prv_role_c

UNION

SELECT p2.hsp_account_id
, p2.cpt_other_prov_id
, h2.cpt_other_prov_rl_c
, zcp2.NAME

from dbo.hsp_acct_cpt_prvdr p2

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HSP_ACCT_CPT_PRVRO h2
ON p2.hsp_account_id = h2.hsp_account_id
AND p2.GROUP_LINE = h2.GROUP_LINE

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ZC_OTH_PRV_ROLE_HA zcp2
ON h2.cpt_other_prov_rl_c = zcp2.oth_prv_role_c

UNION

SELECT p3.hsp_account_id
, p3.icd_other_prov_id
, h3.ICD_OTHER_PROV_RL_C
, zcp3.NAME
       
from dbo.HSP_ACCT_PX_PRVDRS p3

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HSP_ACCT_PX_PRVROL h3
ON p3.hsp_account_id = h3.hsp_account_id
AND p3.group_line = h3.group_line

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ZC_OTH_PRV_ROLE_HA zcp3
ON h3.icd_other_prov_rl_c = zcp3.oth_prv_role_c

UNION 

SELECT hsp_account_id
, CPT_PERF_PROV_ID
, ''
, 'Surgeon/Performing'

FROM dbo.HSP_ACCT_CPT_CODES

UNION

SELECT hsp_account_id
, attending_prov_id
, ''
, 'Attending'

from dbo.hsp_account

WHERE attending_prov_id IS NOT NULL

UNION 

SELECT hsp_account_id
, adm_prov_id
, ''
, 'Admitting'

from dbo.hsp_account

WHERE adm_prov_id IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT h5.hsp_account_id
, p5.prov_id
, p5.TRTMNT_TEAM_REL_C
, zcp5.NAME
            
from dbo.hsp_trtmt_team p5

INNER JOIN dbo.pat_enc h5 
on p5.pat_enc_csn_id = h5.pat_enc_csn_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zc_trtmt_team_rel zcp5
ON p5.TRTMNT_TEAM_REL_C = zcp5.TRTMNT_TEAM_REL_C
WHERE p5.TRTMNT_TEAM_REL_C IN ('3','5','6','7','12','13','23','24','25','53','58','63','67','68','72','76','104',
                               '2101997001','2101997002','2101997003','2101997004','2101997005','2101997006'))


, prov2 as
( 
SELECT DISTINCT hsp_account_id
, other_prov_id
, name

from prov1)
---------------------------------------------------------------HB Query------------------------------

SELECT
    NULL                                    "PB HAR" 
  , HSP.hsp_account_id                      "HB HAR" 
  , NULL                                    "PB Transaction ID" 
  , PATHB.pat_mrn_id                        "MRN" 
  , Cast (PATHB.birth_date AS DATE)         "DOB" 
  , PATHB.pat_name                          "Patient Name" 
  , HSP.tot_chgs                            "Charges"
  , HSP.tot_pmts                            "Payments" 
  , HSP.tot_adj                             "Adjustments" 
  , HSP.tot_acct_bal                        "Balance" 
  , ACLS.acct_class_ha_c                    "Account Class Code" 
  , ACLS.name                               "Account Class Name" 
  , Cast (HSP.adm_date_time AS DATE)        "HAR Admission Date" 
  , Cast (HSP.disch_date_time AS DATE)      "HAR Discharge Date" 
  , NULL                                    "PB Tx Service Date"
  , EPM2.payor_id                           "Payer ID" 
  , EPM2.payor_name                         "Payer" 
  , ACBS.name                               "Account Bill Status" 
  , CSTS.name                               "Coding Status" 
  , cpt1.cpt_code                           "Procedure Code 1"
  , cpt2.cpt_code                           "Procedure Code 2"
  , cpt3.cpt_code                           "Procedure Code 3"
  , cpt4.cpt_code                           "Procedure Code 4"
  , cpt5.cpt_code                           "Procedure Code 5"
  , msdrg.ms_drg_code                       "DRG" 
  , patstat.name                            "Discharge Disposition" 
  , prov2.other_prov_id                     "Provider ID"   
  , TRTPROV.prov_name                       "Provider Name" 
  , prov2.name                              "Provider Role" 
  
FROM 
  dbo.hsp_account                           HSP 

  INNER JOIN dbo.hsp_acct_sbo               SBO 
  ON HSP.hsp_account_id = SBO.hsp_account_id 

  INNER JOIN dbo.patient                    PATHB 
  ON HSP.pat_id = PATHB.pat_id 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN prov2
  ON hsp.hsp_account_id = prov2.hsp_account_id

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.clarity_ser           TRTPROV 
  ON prov2.other_prov_id = TRTPROV.prov_id 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HSP_ACCT_CPT_CODES    cpt1
  ON HSP.hsp_account_id = cpt1.hsp_account_id
  AND cpt1.LINE = 1

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HSP_ACCT_CPT_CODES    cpt2
  ON HSP.hsp_account_id = cpt2.hsp_account_id
  AND cpt2.LINE = 2

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HSP_ACCT_CPT_CODES    cpt3
  ON HSP.hsp_account_id = cpt3.hsp_account_id
  AND cpt3.LINE = 3

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HSP_ACCT_CPT_CODES    cpt4
  ON HSP.hsp_account_id = cpt4.hsp_account_id
  AND cpt4.LINE = 4

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HSP_ACCT_CPT_CODES    cpt5
  ON HSP.hsp_account_id = cpt5.hsp_account_id
  AND cpt5.LINE = 5

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zc_acct_class_ha      ACLS 
  ON HSP.acct_class_ha_c = ACLS.acct_class_ha_c 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hsd_base_class_map    MAP 
  ON ACLS.acct_class_ha_c = MAP.acct_class_map_c 
  AND 
  MAP.mapping_active_f_yn = 'Y' 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zc_acct_basecls_ha    BASECLS 
  ON MAP.base_class_map_c = BASECLS.acct_basecls_ha_c 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.clarity_epm           EPM2 
  ON HSP.primary_payor_id = EPM2.payor_id 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zc_acct_billsts_ha    ACBS 
  ON HSP.acct_billsts_ha_c = ACBS.acct_billsts_ha_c 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zc_coding_sts_ha      CSTS 
  ON HSP.coding_status_c = CSTS.coding_status_c 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zc_mc_pat_status      patstat
  ON HSP.patient_status_c = patstat.pat_status_c

  LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
    SELECT 
       hardrgs.hsp_account_id       "HSP_ACCOUNT_ID" 
      ,hardrgs.drg_mpi_code         "MS_DRG_Code" 
      ,drg.drg_name                 "MS_DRG_DESCRIPTION" 
      ,drgidtype.id_type_name       "DRG_ID_TYPE"  
      ,Row_number() OVER(partition BY hardrgs.hsp_account_id ORDER BY hardrgs.drg_id_type_id DESC)  MS_DRG_RANK

    FROM
     
      dbo.hsp_acct_mult_drgs            hardrgs 

      INNER JOIN dbo.identity_id_type   drgidtype  
      ON hardrgs.drg_id_type_id =drgidtype.id_type

      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.clarity_drg   drg      
      ON hardrgs.drg_id = drg.drg_id 

    WHERE 
      drgidtype.id_type_name LIKE '%MS-DRG%' 
    AND hardrgs.drg_mpi_code IS NOT NULL 
    )    msdrg ON HSP.hsp_account_id = msdrg.hsp_account_id AND msdrg.ms_drg_rank=1

WHERE 
    EPM2.payor_id IN (1046, 1090, 1071, 2008, 1076) 
AND 
    HSP.serv_area_id = 10 
AND 
    (SBO.sbo_har_type_c IS NULL 
        OR SBO.sbo_har_type_c = 0) 
AND 
    HSP.disch_date_time BETWEEN Dateadd (year, -1, Getdate()) AND Getdate()
AND
    HSP.acct_billsts_ha_c <> 40

UNION

---------------------------------------------------------------PB Query------------------------------

SELECT 
    pbmod.hosp_acct_id                      "PB HAR"
  , pat_enc.hsp_account_id                  "HB HAR"    
  , pbtx.TX_ID                              "PB Transaction ID"
  , PAT.pat_mrn_id                          "MRN" 
  , Cast (PAT.birth_date AS DATE)           "DOB" 
  , PAT.pat_name                            "Patient Name" 
  , pbtx.amount                             "Charges"
  , pbtx.TOTAL_MATCH_AMT 
    - pbtx.TOTAL_MTCH_ADJ                   "Payments"
  , pbtx.total_mtch_adj                     "Adjustments"
  , pbtx.outstanding_amt                    "Balance"       
  , ACLS2.acct_class_ha_c                   "Account Class Code" 
  , ACLS2.NAME                              "Account Class Name" 
  , Cast (HA.adm_date_time AS DATE)         "HAR Admission Date" 
  , Cast (HA.disch_date_time AS DATE)       "HAR Discharge Date" 
  , Cast (pbtx.service_date AS DATE)        "PB Tx Service Date"
  , EPM.payor_id                            "Payer ID" 
  , EPM.payor_name                          "Payer Name" 
  , ACBS2.NAME                              "Account Bill Status" 
  , NULL                                    "Coding Status"   
  , EAP.PROC_CODE                           "Procedure Code 1" 
  , NULL                                    "Procedure Code 2"
  , NULL                                    "Procedure Code 3"
  , NULL                                    "Procedure Code 4"
  , NULL                                    "Procedure Code 5"
  , NULL                                    "DRG" 
  , patstat.NAME                            "Discharge Disposition"
  , SER.PROV_ID                             "Provider ID" 
  , SER.PROV_NAME                           "Provider Name" 
  , 'Service Provider'                      "Provider Role" 

FROM 
  dbo.ARPB_TRANSACTIONS pbtx 

  INNER JOIN dbo.ARPB_TX_MODERATE pbmod
  ON pbtx.TX_ID = pbmod.TX_ID

  INNER JOIN dbo.hsp_account  HA 
  ON pbmod.hosp_acct_id = HA.hsp_account_id 

  INNER JOIN dbo.patient  PAT 
  ON pbtx.patient_id = PAT.pat_id 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CLARITY_EAP EAP 
  ON pbtx.proc_id = EAP.PROC_ID 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.clarity_epm    EPM 
  ON pbtx.ORIGINAL_EPM_ID = EPM.payor_id 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.clarity_ser    SER 
  ON pbtx.serv_provider_id = SER.prov_id 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.pat_enc
  ON pbtx.pat_enc_csn_id = pat_enc.pat_enc_csn_id 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zc_mc_pat_status patstat
  ON HA.patient_status_c = patstat.pat_status_c 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zc_acct_billsts_ha  ACBS2 
  ON HA.acct_billsts_ha_c = ACBS2.acct_billsts_ha_c 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zc_acct_class_ha  ACLS2 
  ON HA.acct_class_ha_c = ACLS2.acct_class_ha_c 

WHERE 
  pbtx.TX_TYPE_C = 1
AND
  pbtx.void_date IS NULL
AND
  EPM.payor_id IN (1046, 1090, 1071, 2008, 1076) 
AND 
  pbtx.service_date BETWEEN Dateadd (year, -1, Getdate()) AND Getdate() 
AND 
  pbtx.service_area_id = 10  
AND
  EAP.PROC_CODE <> 'CHARGEINHB'

ORDER BY 
hsp.hsp_account_id
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What's the database? Looks easy to with `LAG()`.

Comment: What's the ordering on the rows?

Comment: @The Impaler I'm using dbo schema - SQL Server 18

Comment: @shawnt00 Ordering by hsp.hsp_account_id

Comment: `case when pbtx.amount = lag(pbtx.amount) over (partition by pbmod.hosp_acct_id, pat_enc.hsp_account_id order by hsp.hsp_account_id) then null else pbtx.amount end`

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks that worked! This is exactly what I need.